# In Scala 3 is `isEmpty` on a sequence faster than `length == 0`?

Tags: scala, performance, collections, sequence, scala-3

In Scala 3 I have a sequence defined, for example:

```
val seq = List(1,8,9)
```

Is the operation `seq.isEmpty` faster than `seq.length == 0`?

Thinking about it, `isEmpty *should* be faster (because it only has to check whether a first "next" element does not exist), but is it in Scala 3 really implemented like this?

Comment: You should always prefer to use `isEmpty` over `length == 0`, it may be way faster and is clearer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Scala 3 still uses Scala 2.13 standard library.

On a `List`, the 2 operations are defined as follow:

```scala
// https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/951cc9b1cc3dccd36762de4d6176bf8fd76a842f/src/library/scala/collection/immutable/List.scala#L142

override final def isEmpty: Boolean = this eq Nil
```

```scala
// https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/951cc9b1cc3dccd36762de4d6176bf8fd76a842f/src/library/scala/collection/immutable/List.scala#L361

override final def length: Int = {
  var these = this
  var len = 0
  while (!these.isEmpty) {
    len += 1
    these = these.tail
  }
  len
}
```

It's thus expected that `isEmpty` is way faster than `length` for `List`s.

Other collections types may have different implementations.

*Note that in general you should always run some benchmarks (with JMH for instance) if you want to compare two implementations. The theorical cost and the actual time spent can be significantly different for many reasons including JVM optimizations.*

Comment: I'd add that 2.13 introduced operations like `sizeCompare` or `sizeIs` to make the comparison only as costly as necessary to answer whether the expectation is true, e.g. `List(1,2,3,4,5,6,7).sizeIs == 0` would evaluate only the first `hasNext` to answer that question.